# Textblock crash and Image refresh

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-mobile, visual-studio-2015

I have some problem with the UI of my app. First of all the textblock crashes when I try to scroll it. It happen only when there are lots of rows in it (like 500). I use this textblock to view the log file saved in the ApplicationData folder.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollLog" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="2">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextLog" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

There's a maximum of rows that textblock can handle?

Second problem is the Image control which sometimes it doesn't refresh.
I use this code to load different images in it.

```
file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(ImageName);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
await CurrentWallpaper.SetSourceAsync(stream);
CurrentWallpaperImage.Source = CurrentWallpaper;
stream.Dispose();
```

How can I solve this problem? Maybe can I force the refresh of the control?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: I believe there is a 2048 pixel height limitation for a UI control.   Maybe this will help fix the issue http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx